# Dart type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Tags: dart

I am using `num` type in dart to parse json data, As our server implemented in NodeJS, integer and double type has no meaning, when the server send a json field with value `4` and `4.0` both are `4` in json string, So I used `num` to parse json numbers

In my flutter app, I need to pass parsed data to a `double` variable, When server send number with fractional part (i.e. `4.1`) everything is ok, As `runtimeType` of parsed `num` is `double`
But when server send without fractional part, the `runtimeType` of parsed `num` is `int` and I have `Dart type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'` error

I am looking for a way to say Dart that strongly check `num` type too, if I pass `num` to a `double` variable throw an error

I don't want to turn off `implicit-casts`, As I have many `dynamic` type that implicitly casted

Comment: It does not make sense to use `num`.  For each of your fields, it either should be an `int` if it's always known to be an integer, or it should be `double` if it might be a floating point value.  And there should be no problem using `double.parse` on strings without a fractional part.

Comment: (@julemand101 The Null Safety feature still allows implicit downcast from `dynamic`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dart JSON parser parses integer numerals as `int` values and fractional numerals as `double`. So, a JSON numeral of `4.1` is read into a double, so is `4.0`, but a plain `4` becomes an `int`. There is no way to configure that, you have to deal with the value you get.

If you want to use a JSON number value as a `double`, use the `.toDouble()` method on the value before assigning it to a `double` variable: `double d = jsonValue["name"].toDouble();` or `var d = (jsonValue["name"] as num).toDouble();`